# Counting with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a question with streaming in general but for the scope of the question let us restrict ourselves with Kafka Streams. Let's narrow the scope further by restricting our problem to just word count, or perhaps counting in general. Say I have a stream of some key and a value, key could be a string (and lets say we can have many strings, except empty strings, consisting of any character in the world) and value is a integer, now we are building a word count app, if the total number of words in the vocabulary is a trillion we cannot store them in some local cache. If a word `w` is seen with a value `x` i need to update the existing count for `w` to `X+x` assuming `X` was the previous count, how will I build this application. I cannot store a trillion words in a `KTable` or any other local storage native to Kafka, how will I build this app? Is my understanding wrong about Streams or how they work.

Answer (score 4):

Because Kafka Streams scales horizontally, you can deploy as many application instances as you want. Thus, it should actually be possible to build this application. Note that the `KTable` state will be sharded over all machines.

If you assume a trillion keys, and each key is about 100 bytes, you would need about 100 TB of storage. To give some head room, in practice you might want to provision 200 TB. Thus, 100 instances with 2 TB each should do the job.

For this, your input topic would need to have 100 partitions, what is not a problem for Kafka though.

Comment: Thank you for the response, what I don't understand is that how do applications outside of Kafka will get access to the data. For e.g. if I were to create a middleware service that wants to show the count of any word in UI of my application, will `KTable` grant me that access, say i get a `GET` request with request parameter specifying a word for which the count needs to be returned.

Comment: Kafka Streams has a feature called "Interactive Queries" that allow you to query the individual shards and to locate the correct shard. Check out the docs for details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html -- you would need to build your own REST layer (or similar) on top, that exposes a `GET` though. An example implementation can be found on Github: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Answer (score 0):

(+1 to what Matthias J. Sax said in his answer.)

An alternative approach is to use probabilistic counting, which has *significantly* lower storage and memory footprint; i.e., to use a probabilistic data structure like [Count-min Sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch) (CMS) instead of a linear data structure like Kafka Streams' `KTable` or a Java `HashMap`.

There is an example called `ProbabilisticCounting` available that demonstrates how to perform probabilistic counting with CMS in Kafka Streams: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples ([direct link](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/scala/io/confluent/examples/streams/ProbabilisticCountingScalaIntegrationTest.scala) for Confluent Platform version 5.2.1 / Apache Kafka 2.2.1)

I have successfully used probabilistic counting for similar use cases where the key space is very large (in your case: trillions of keys).